# Why mongodb locks database instead of collecton

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

I read some information in [mongodb manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/) regarding locking of database. It says that mongodb implements some sort of reader-writer lock for multiple clients working with database. It seems absolutely logical, when we need to ensure data integrity.

My question is why mongodb locks databases instead of collections?

Answer (score 2):

The [feature](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1240) simply isn't done yet. It's planned for 2.4+ (maybe 2.5?). Until 2.2, it was a global lock and not a database-level lock.

Comment: One correction, it isn't planned for 2.4, last I heard it was 2.5 but it seems the JIRA has been set back to planing bucket instead

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't heard that. At MongoSV, they'd said 2.4 still (Nov. 2012). Bummer.

Comment: Oh that I didn't know....hmm I must admit they haven't been good at telling people these things recently who don't attend the conferences